# Write text to textbox after dropdown menu has been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, textbox

I am looking to add text to a textbox with the selected text from the dropdown menu and place a ',' after.().

```
<select>
<option value="1">This</option>
<option value="2">is</option>
<option value="3">test</option>
</select>
```

Now when you select the option 'is' the textbox gets updated with 'is,'. Now still on the same page you select 'This' the textbox gets updated with 'is, This,'. Reload the page and do it the other way around and you get 'This, is,'.

Hope you understand what I am trying to do here, the  will contains values from the database so I cannot know what the values are exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us some code and then we can help

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
<select id="dropdownId">
    <option value="1">This</option>
    <option value="2">is</option>
    <option value="3">test</option>
</select>
<input id="textboxId" type="text" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dropdownId').on('change', function () {
        $('#textboxId').val($('#textboxId').val() + $('#dropdownId option:selected').text() + ', ');
    });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grzh8/)

Comment: This doesnt seem to work in my code.. I use this JS file:   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> and then add your code, doesnt work. Tried with 1.10 aswell :/